# Copying to MicroSD card from Ubuntu 9.04 Is slow

Tags: linux, usb, sd-card

When I copy stuff to my class 6 16GB microsd card it seems very slow.  This is true with multiple readers and computers, but I have only tested it with ubuntu 9.04.  In /var/log/messages I get the following a bunch of times during the transfer:

```
[355335.112041] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[355368.112060] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[355403.116565] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[355436.112041] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[355470.112311] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
[355534.112403] usb 1-4: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 3
```

Is this a bad card, I might go try it with a different OS, but maybe someone has seen this?  I am copying to the first partition, the partition looks like:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1        1822    14635183+   b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sdb2            1823        1920      787185   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3            1921        1953      265072+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of `lspci`, `lsusb` and `cat /proc/scsi/scsi` when the reader is connected?

Comment: nagul, thanks for the help.  I decided the card is messed up, couldn't even delete partitions with multiple readers and hosts.  New card came, seems to working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried other cards in the same readers and gotten transfer speeds? It could be none of the readers support the highest transfer speeds.

The resets, from what I know, could be a bad card, a bad reader, or a bad USB port. The USB or card connection could be intermittent and disconnect for a moment due to fan vibrations from the computer. It could also be drivers, but on multiple computers, it seems unlikely (unless they are all Dell).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an older motherboard with older USB version. There could be compatibility issue with the older (low speed) USB interface  taking to device with high speed usb card.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't think Ubuntu could use an SD card in SD mode--I thought it was using the older MMC mode because Linux can't abide by the SD consortium's restrictions on SD mode.

Short version: blame the makers of SD, not Ubuntu.

Edit: I stand corrected--user is using an SD reader over USB, not an SD reader built-in to the machine.

Comment: This is completely wrong. First, when using a USB reader (which is the case here), Linux is _not_ talking the SD protocol, but the "USB storage" protocol, which is publicly documented (it is the card reader itself which implements the SD protocol). Second, the necessary documentation has been out for years (check commit 335eadf on the Linux kernel - it is from 2005).